# Why does rustc automatically downgrade its version?

Tags: rust, rustup

I was trying to upgrade rust. I tried uninstalling (1.60.0) and reinstalling. The new version is 1.73.0. But when I ran rustc it automatically downloaded 1.60.0 and reverted to 1.60.0. Wonder how can I force it to use the new version?

```
info: profile set to 'default'
info: default host triple is aarch64-apple-darwin
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-aarch64-apple-darwin'
info: latest update on 2023-10-05, rust version 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
info: downloading component 'cargo'
info: downloading component 'clippy'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
info: downloading component 'rustc'
 54.4 MiB /  54.4 MiB (100 %)  27.7 MiB/s in  2s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rustfmt'
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: installing component 'clippy'
info: installing component 'rust-docs'
 13.8 MiB /  13.8 MiB (100 %)   5.5 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'rust-std'
 24.5 MiB /  24.5 MiB (100 %)  21.1 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'rustc'
 54.4 MiB /  54.4 MiB (100 %)  23.3 MiB/s in  2s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'rustfmt'
info: default toolchain set to 'stable-aarch64-apple-darwin'

  stable-aarch64-apple-darwin installed - rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)


Rust is installed now. Great!

To get started you may need to restart your current shell.
This would reload your PATH environment variable to include
Cargo's bin directory ($HOME/.cargo/bin).

To configure your current shell, run:
source "$HOME/.cargo/env"

(base) % rustc -V
info: syncing channel updates for '1.60.0-aarch64-apple-darwin'
info: latest update on 2022-04-07, rust version 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
info: downloading component 'cargo'
info: downloading component 'clippy'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
info: downloading component 'rustc'
info: downloading component 'rustfmt'
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: installing component 'clippy'
info: installing component 'rust-docs'
info: installing component 'rust-std'
info: installing component 'rustc'
info: installing component 'rustfmt'
rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
```

Comment: There is very likely a [rustup version override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) in the environment or on the directory where you ran `rustc -V`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways rust could be forced to using a specific compiler version ([overrides](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html))

**1. The `RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN` environment variable**

**2. A [Directory override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#directory-overrides)**

> Directories can be assigned their own Rust toolchain with rustup override. When a directory has an override then any time rustc or cargo is run inside that directory, or one of its child directories, the override toolchain will be invoked.

> The per-directory overrides are stored in a configuration file in rustup's home directory.

To see the active toolchain use `rustup show` and `rustup override unset` to remove it.

**3. The [toolchain file](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#the-toolchain-file)**

(`rust-toolchain.toml` or `rust-toolchain`) can set a specific Rust version.

For example

```ini
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2020-07-10"
...
```

**4. The default version can be set directly.**

Use `rustup default` to view the default global toolchain.

Comment: Thanks, in my case, it turns out to be 3. There is a rust-toolchain.toml in the parent directory.